# SP2-0552: Bind Variable "NEW" is not declared

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to learn pl/sql triggers. I am trying to create a simple trigger by tracking tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm but I got below error. I searched on the internet but could not find the solution. Could you help me on this issue?

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER display_salary_changes 
  BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON ok.customers 
  FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
    sal_diff NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
    sal_diff := :NEW.salary - :OLD.salary; 
END; 
/ 


Trıgger DISPLAY_SALARY_CHANGES created.

SP2-0552: Bind Variable "NEW" is not declared.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Edit: I am using Sql Developer Version 4.1.1

[image]

Comment: you try to compile in sqlplus or something others (sql developer, plsql developer, toad) ?

Comment: @АнатолийПредеин, I am using Sql Developer Version 4.1.1

Comment: file -> new -> All items -> Sql File (Database File) -> and past code in window and then press F5. see screenshot https://gyazo.com/0763ec50a7aa637a66305366f7bed5ee without errors

Comment: @АнатолийПредеин, Thanks for your answer but what I see is: https://i.imgur.com/yZcYCYd.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me (example from your link, but it's basically the same as your post):

```
SQL> create table demo (id integer, salary number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger display_salary_changes
  2  before delete or insert or update on demo
  3  for each row
  4  when (new.id > 0)
  5  declare
  6     sal_diff number;
  7  begin
  8     sal_diff := :new.salary  - :old.salary;
  9     dbms_output.put_line('Old salary: ' || :old.salary);
 10     dbms_output.put_line('New salary: ' || :new.salary);
 11     dbms_output.put_line('Salary difference: ' || sal_diff);
 12  end;
 13  /

Trigger created.

SQL> show errors
No errors.
SQL> insert into demo (id, salary) values (1, 100);
Old salary:
New salary: 100
Salary difference:

1 row created.

SQL> update demo set salary = salary * 1.1 where id = 1;
Old salary: 100
New salary: 110
Salary difference: 10

1 row updated.
```

In your example it shows

```
Trıgger DISPLAY_SALARY_CHANGES created.
```

which doesn't look like SQL*Plus output. What tool did you use?

After that it gives a SQL*Plus `SP2-0552` error about an undefined bind variable, followed by

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

What procedure was that? I suspect this is the output from a script with some other step that is failing after the trigger is created.

Is the trigger valid? You can normally right-click and check properties in desktop tools, or at the SQL*Plus prompt enter

```
show errors trigger display_salary_changes
```

Comment: I am using Sql Developer Version 4.1.1 and I am only running above script.

Comment: And is the trigger valid?

Comment: Find the trigger in the object browser (left hand panel, below Connections), and see if it's marked with a red X.

Comment: Also, you can right-click the trigger name in the browser tree and select 'Edit'. Then it will open it in a code editor window and it shouldn't get confused about bind variables. (There may be some way to change a default SQL Worksheet into a code editor but I'm not that familiar with SQL Developer.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER test_trg 
  BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON test 
  FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
    sal_diff NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
    sal_diff := :new.d - :old.d; 
END; 
/
```

Comment: Now: SP2-0552: Bind Variable "new" is not declared.

Comment: It got complied here in my system. Check if something else wrong in ur program.

Comment: I am using Sql Developer Version 4.1.1. Could it be the problem?

Comment: Sql developer is only a interface to access Oracle. Check your oracle version. Also as far i understand even for the lowest version of Oracle will support this trigger. There is nothing wrong in your code and your code must compile and run. If you can tell what are you really wanted to achieve with creating this trigger, then i guess experts can help.

Comment: @Raj_Te, it's a learning exercise. He's trying to get a tutorialspoint.com demo to work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check you column name. I have tried your code below and I got output.

```
create table test
(
no number(10),
sal number(10)
);

CREATE OR replace TRIGGER test_tr 
  BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON test 
  FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
    sal_diff NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
    sal_diff := :NEW.sal - :OLD.sal; 
    dbms_output.put_line(sal_diff);
END; 
/ 



insert into test values(1,100);

update test set sal=200 where no=1;
```

Output :

```
1 rows inserted.


4 rows updated.
100
100
100
100

1 rows inserted.
```

Comment: I am using Sql Developer Version 4.1.1 and when I run your script again I got same error

Answer (score 0):

I think it is missing the "REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD" sentence:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER [trigger_name]
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON [table_name]
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW
```